# Using only phone number and 2-step verification as login

Tags: mobile-application, login, security, smartphone, sms

Is **requiring** **the** **user to login using phone number and 2-step verification** bad design? I have only seen 2-step verification as an EXTRA layer of protection, not a requirement. The only thing similar is a product like Twilo, that sends you a SMS code, but the code never changes and acts as your password.

Can anyone shed some advice on this concept?

Comment: It really depends on your security requirements. Can you share more about your application?

Comment: You said, the code never changes and thats the password. I didnt get?

Comment: _to login using phone number and 2-step verification_ do you mean like send them a text to their phone and then ask for the 3 digits pin generated by an app, or only one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you think about using the extra verification for. I worked in the banking sector, and there it make complete sense to add phone number verification for 2 reasons.

1, it is more secure and the users data is safer this way.

2, the psychological factor. The user will feel safer using 2-step verification when handling sensitive information and might tend to using your website over one that doesn't have 2 step.

So analyse what market you will be designing for and then asses this information with the extra effort of 2step verification. In general I would go away from extra verification as it's quite a bit of extra work and users don't like the extra work. Keep it simple is my motto.

But on the other hand for marketing purposes you will have a contact number, which could also come in handy incase you need to contact the customer urgently.

Having a user login only with 2step verification is a valid option, but I would only recommend using it if this level of security is required.

Comment: thanks for the advice, from the perspective of a user, requiring 2-step is annoying but I guess for the purpose of what I am designing it is a valid reason.